the <ul> is not as wide as it seems which causes the image next to it to be on it
I am doing an assignment of mine, I need to create a website. Firstly I want to make the base structure I will use on all the pages. My problem is that in the header the image (top.png) overflows to the menu on the left, I want it to be seemless aka menu on the left and picture on right so that this two would fill the whole row.
(I am a starter so if the whole structure can be "coded" better, I would appreciate some facelift to it.)


.header-content {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.header-content img {
    width: 80%;
}

.header-content ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 20%;
}

.header-content li {
    margin-bottom: 1px; 
}

.header-content a {
    display: block; 
    padding: 10px 20px; 
    background-color: #f9c9692c; 
    color: #fff; 
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #191919;
}
<header>
    <div class="header-content">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="current">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
        </ul>
        <img src="top.png" alt="Image Description">
    </div>
</header>




Your HTML is invalid. Please run it through a validator and fix the errors

Cut the code down to just the specific CSS and HTML you need to demonstrate the problem. See [mcve]

set the correct flex values on the .header-content children (ul and img). Specifically flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis. Also, you have the img set left: 100px, but the ul width: 200%, shouldn't they be the same value?

I did validation on the website then fixed the issues, and changed the code in the post so  it' just the html and css of the issue.

I converted your code into a snippet.
Remove .header-content a { width: 100%; }, or set .header-content a { box-sizing: border-box; }:


.header-content {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.header-content img {
    width: 80%;
}

.header-content ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 20%;
}

.header-content li {
    margin-bottom: 1px; 
}

.header-content a {
    display: block; 
    padding: 10px 20px; 
    background-color: #f9c9692c; 
    color: #fff; 
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
    /* width: 100%; */
    text-align: center;
    color: #191919;
}
<header>
    <div class="header-content">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="current">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
        </ul>
        <img src="top.png" alt="Image Description">
    </div>
</header>



P.S. Better start your css with a rule:
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

